# Trouble with apostrophe in arcpy search cursor where clause

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I've put together a tkinter form and python script for downloading files from an ftp site.  The filenames are in the attribute table of a shapefile, as well as an overall Name that the filenames correspond too. In other words I look up a Name such as "CABOT" and download the filename 34092_18.tif.  However, if a Name has an apostrophe, such as "O'KEAN", it's giving me trouble.  I try to replace the apostrophe, like I've done in previous scripts, but it doesn't download anything....

```
    whereExp = quadField + " = " + "'" + quadName.replace("'", '"') + "'"
    quadFields = ["FILENAME"]

    c = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(collarlessQuad, quadFields, whereExp)
    for row in c:
        tifFile = row[0]
        tifName = quadName.replace("'", '') + '_' + tifFile
        #fullUrl = ftpUrl + tifFile
        local_filename = os.path.join(downloadDir, tifName)
        lf = open(local_filename, "wb")
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + tifFile, lf.write)
        lf.close()
```

Here is an example of a portion of a script that works fine by replacing the apostrophe....

```
where_clause = quadField + " = " + "'" + quad.replace("'", '"') + "'"
#out_quad = quad.replace("'", "") + ".shp"  

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(quadTable, "quadLayer")
select_out_feature_class = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("quadLayer", "NEW_SELECTION",  where_clause)
```

Comment: Would you provide an example of a *good* ```whereExp``` string that contains an apostrophe?

Comment: I did wwii.  It's underneath 'Here is an example of a portion of a script that works fine by replacing the apostrophe....'